# Convert SQL code to R (using dplyr)

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, code-conversion

I am trying to convert SQL code to R using dplyr. I almost did it but I have an issue with the last part of the code.

I have to display only the counties (denloc) where the sum of fines (valamenda) to be greater than the sum (valamenda) in "Calarasi".

This is my query in SQL:

```
    select denloc, sum (valamenda) as total 
      from contraventions c inner join counties co on c.idloc = co.idloc
      where datacontr between date '1/1/2014' and date '31/12/2014' 
      group by denloc
      having sum(valamenda) >
              (select sum (valamenda) as total 
              from contraventions c inner join counties co on c.idloc = co.idloc
              where denloc = 'Calarasi' and datacontr between date '1/1/2014' and date '31/12/2014'
              group by denloc)
```

This is what I did so far in R

```
   result <- inner_join(Contraventions, Counties) %>%
             select(denloc, datacontr, valamenda) %>%
             filter(year(datacontr)== '2014') %>%
             group_by(denloc) %>%
             summarize(Total_Amenda = sum(valamenda))
```

The result is:

```
              denloc    Total_Amenda

          1   Bucuresti     1000
          2   Calarasi       850
          3   Cluj Napoca    150
          4   Giurgiu        1500
          5   Iasi           250
```

As I already told, I have to display only those counties (denloc) where the sum of fine (Total_Amenda) is greater than the sum (Total_Amenda) in "Calarasi".

Thus my result should look like:

```
         denloc    Total_Amenda

     1   Giurgiu        1500
     2   Bucuresti      1000
```

Should I create a variable or should I make two tables and then compare them ?

Comment: Why not simply filter again after `summarize()`? like : `%>%filter(Total_Amenda>Total_Amenda[denloc=="Calarasi"])`

Comment: THANK YOU A LOT, it works. I was trying to do the same, just was using wrong structure of the filter :)

Answer (score 0):

After trying to convert SQL code to R code manually, you can cross check whether dplyr package R code is yielding the same result by using the show_query() function after the dplyr code.